# point clouds in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-sets

What is the purpose of point clouds in machine learning?

Consider the following suggestion:
Say I have a table (per year) of records (such as days) each of which is made of n real numbers such as temperatures per hour). Can I use the table as a data point to do classification of the year as hot/cold or something like that?

Any real-world examples of point cloud data?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud

Comment: I know point clouds can represent shapes in graphics. What else though, specifically in machine learning?

Answer (score 1):

The term "point cloud" is normally used to refer to a set of points (locations) in 3D space.  So, a table of temperatures would normally not be called a "point cloud".